# Shrink <figcaption> to sibling <img> and keep it responsive

Tags: css, figure

This is the problem illustrated:
[image: here]

I want to make the border which is figure tag to fit the img.

This is the html structure:

```
<div class="container">
    <figure>
        <img src="" alt="">
        <figcaption></figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
```

and this is the css:

```
figure {
    border: 1px solid $color-light-gray;
    padding: 5px;

    img {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: 100%
    }

    figcaption {
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is doing exactly what you would like it to. If you want a border around the image, why not just use what you have done on `figure` on `img`?

Comment: the problem is in <figcaption> I don't want it to pass <img> width

Comment: @Dave also giving <figure> a fixed width will make it not responsive

Answer (score 1):

Use `display:table` in figure and `display:table-caption` in `figcaption`

Answer (score 0):

```
figure {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100%;

    img {
        max-width: 50%;
        min-width: 50%;
        outline: solid 1px black;
    }

    figcaption {
        text-align: center;
        width: 50%;
    }
}
```

Just assign `figcaption` the width you require. Assign a`max-width` to `img` if you only wish for it to go half way across.

Comment: unfortunately that's not the desired result, is there a way to make figure max-width equal to img width?

Answer (score 0):

Just scale your image according to your convenience, the parent div will scale on its own, like

```css
figure {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px;

}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}

figcaption {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <figure>
        <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg" alt="">
        <figcaption>Caption Caption Caption Caption Caption</figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
```